# Can't Save data into multiple tables from one form in CakePHP 2.5.1

Tags: mysql, cakephp, orm, cakephp-2.x

I am new in CakePHP, developing a cloud application using CakePHP 2.5.1 and MySQL. I have following tables:

```
users

  id ,
  person_id(FK- people.id),
  username,
  password

people

  id, 
  parent_id(FK- people.id), 
  firsr_name,
  last_name,
  role

addresses

  address_id,
  person_id(FK- people.id),
  street,
  house no,
  post code,
  city
```

Foreign key `people.parent_id` refers to `primary_key people.id` of the same table `people`. Value of `role` can be `manager` or `customer`. If `manager`, the value of `people.id` will be assigned to `people.parent_id`.

In my registration form, there will be following input fields:

```
-username
-password
-first name
-last name
-street
-house no
-post code
-city
-role
```

in the view (`view/Users/add.ctp`), I have following fields:

```
         $options = array('manager' => 'Manager', 'customer' => 'Customer');
              $attributes = array('legend' => false); 
              echo $this->Form->radio('Person.role', $options, $attributes);    


              echo $this->Form->input('User.username');
              echo $this->Form->input('Person.last_name');
              echo $this->Form->input('Person.first_name');

              echo $this->Form->input('Address.street');
              echo $this->Form->input('Address.house_no');
              echo $this->Form->input('Address.post_code');
              echo $this->Form->input('Address.city');
```

the action in `UsersController`:

```
 public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->create();
            if ($this->User->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
                $components = array('Session'); 
                $this->Session->setFlash('Welcome !');
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                __('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.')
            );
        }
    }
```

The problem is the data of first three fields (in users and people tables) are saved, other data (of addresses table) are not saved.

Could anyone tell me what am I missing here ?

Comment: Probably because model `User` is not directly related to model `Address` . To help provide a fix, please post the code for  `Users::add()`.

Comment: you mean i should post the code of add() action from UsersController or from add.ctp ?

Comment: Yep, sorry about the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model `User` is not directly related to model `Address`. However, it is related through model `Person`, where `Person hasMany Address`.

Try the following.

Change your view to:

```
    $options = array('manager' => 'Manager', 'customer' => 'Customer');
    $attributes = array('legend' => false);
    echo $this->Form->radio('Person.role', $options, $attributes);


    echo $this->Form->input('User.username');
    echo $this->Form->input('Person.last_name');
    echo $this->Form->input('Person.first_name');

    echo $this->Form->input('Person.Address.0.street');
    echo $this->Form->input('Person.Address.0.house_no');
    echo $this->Form->input('Person.Address.0.post_code');
    echo $this->Form->input('Person.Address.0.city');
```

And add `'deep'=>true` to `saveAll()` in your `UsersController.add()`:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->saveAll($this->request->data,['deep'=>true])) {
            $components = array('Session'); 
            $this->Session->setFlash('Welcome !');
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(
            __('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.')
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: it will be array('deep' => true). thank you buddy ! it is working now. one thing missing, as we discussed before, in case of manager, People.id should be assigned to People.Parent_id. but it is not happening.

Comment: Exactly, being `['deep'=>true]` the short array syntax. Regarding `parent_id`, you must fill in this field when you are entering a customer, and it must be an existing `Manager.id` (alias of `Person.id`). You could pass this value as a parameter to the `add()` method.